# How do I put my own twist on prewritten adventures

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, published-adventures, story

I am a new DM, and I am quite good at running encounters, making interesting environments to explore and creating compelling NPCs.   I struggle with the storytelling aspects of the game. I know the sort of story I want to tell but I'm not sure how to tell it.

I feel that I need to use pre-written adventures as a crutch to avoid burnout, but I don't know how to take an existing story and add in all the elements I want to have.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what sort of elements you want to add and to what end? It also depends what sort of pre-made adventure you’re using, adding things to e.g. a sandbox campaign is much easier than to a linear one

Comment: Would it be helpful if I added context for what I want things to look like? I tried to be more broad and sorta paint with wide strokes

Comment: @AnnaAG I will work on that

Comment: Yes, add some more context, it's a little too broad at the moment.

Comment: Could provide a specific adventure you want to modify. Murder in Baldur's Gate is more or a sandbox adventure while Dragon Heist has a specific trajectory. I've often used printed adventures as part of a campaign dropping or modifying parts to fit the overall theme.

Comment: I may just think on it and come back with a new more organized post in a few days

Comment: I would urge you to make the edits, even significant edits, here.  I will almost certainly vote for re-opening at that time-- I cannot promise, but I suspect others will as well.  The site just works better this way.

Comment: By the same token, though, I would recommend as much specificity as you reasonably can.  I think if you do that, and the question gets re-opened, we will be able to get you some good answers.